# How to search data in Back4app

Tags: android, database, searchview, back4app

I'm creating an application on android, and I'm using back4app as my back end. How to search data from back4app using Android Search View?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Your question is very vague. Possible clarifications: 'how to use SearchView', 'how to filter Back4app data', 'how to handle asynchronous operations in Android'.

Comment: I want to search data from back4app, I'm going to use Search View, I'm sorry, my English is bad

Answer (score 1):

at the moment I believe that the structure below can help you, it's just a example :)

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.whereEqualTo("playerName", "Dan Stemkoski");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
 public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
        Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " scores");
    } else {
        Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
 }
});
```